# knockoutjs cannot apply bindings to different ids

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jsfiddle, knockout-3.0

I have several views in my project and each applies bindings on its own tag like this:

(note: periods represents more code removed to show the problem I have, I created a fiddle a bit more complete here: http://jsfiddle.net/EYB8E/)

HTML

```
<div id="ui-main"> 
    ... html code bound to mainViewModel here
<div/>

...

<div id="ui-partial"> 
    ...
</div>
```

javascript

```
function MainViewModel() {...};

var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel, document.getElementById("ui-main"));

...
function PartialViewModel() {...};
ko.applyBindings(partialViewModel, document.getElementById("ui-partial"));
```

but the second applyBindings does not apply because: ***"Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."***. (see it in jsFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/EYB8E)

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: your first div is malformed, the closing tag is <div/> instead of </div> causing ui-partial to be inside of ui-main. So ui-partial is bound to the mainViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div />` should be `</div>`.